# One-way biding won't update template with controller

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to change the value of a button by switching the value of a string parameter.

Here is the declaration in my html file :

```
<app-connexion *ngIf="connexionVisible"></app-connexion>
<app-inscription *ngIf="!connexionVisible"></app-inscription>

<ion-button (click)="toggleInscription()">{{status}}</ion-button>
```

here is my controller :

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  connexionVisible: boolean = true;
  status: String = "Inscription";

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  toggleInscription() {

    (this.connexionVisible) ? this.connexionVisible = false:
      this.connexionVisible = true;
    (this.status = "Inscription") ? this.status = "Connexion": this.status =
      "Inscription";
  }

}
```

It only works the first time I'm toggling the button and then stay put with "Connexion", whereas my components conditioned by a boolean are rendering perfectly fine. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with your code.

> You're using the [**assignment(`=`)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) operator instead of the [**equality(`===`)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) operator.

Give this a try to fix it:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  connexionVisible = true;
  status = "Inscription";

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  toggleInscription() {
    this.connexionVisible = !this.connexionVisible;
    this.status = (this.status === "Inscription") ? "Connexion": "Inscription";
  }
}
```